# How To Fix Join Problem Show Same Results

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables, `Customers` And `ListTypeData`. I just want to join these two tables.
I have `CityId` And `DistrictId` In `Customers` table.

It gives me both `City` and `District` same how to fix
for `City` And `District`.

```
  SELECT c.[CustomerId]
        ,c.[Name]
        ,c.[CompanyName]
        ,c.[ShopNo]
        ,list.[Description] AS 'City'
        ,list.[Description] AS 'District' 
  FROM [MakkiRuskFaisalabad].[dbo].[Customers] c
  JOIN [dbo].[ListTypesData] list ON c.CityId = list.ListTypeDataId ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `join` to the `ListTypesData` table a second time:

```
SELECT c.CustomerId
  ,c.Name
  ,c.CompanyName
  ,c.ShopNo
  ,list.Description AS 'City'
  ,list2.Description AS 'District' 
FROM MakkiRuskFaisalabad.dbo.Customers c
    JOIN dbo.ListTypesData list ON c.CityId = list.ListTypeDataId
    JOIN dbo.ListTypesData list2 ON c.DistrictId = list2.ListTypeDataId
```